# How to reference a sub-view in Handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've embedded a series of views into my document using the following code:

```
{{view App.View.PersonProfile.Name itemBinding="person"}}
```

And I'm using the following code for my main container view, and its two sub-views:

```
App.View.PersonProfile = Ember.ContainerView.extend(
{
    tagName: 'a',
    person:  null,
    childViews: ['Name', 'NameAvatar'],

    click: function()
    {
        App.View.Window.Profile.create({ person: this.get('person') });
    },

    name: Ember.View.extend(
    {
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{ view.parentView.person.formalName }}')
    }),

    nameAvatar: Ember.View.extend(
    {
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile
        (
            '<img class="avatar" {{bindAttr src="view.parentView.person.avatar"}} />' +
            '<div class="name">{{ view.parentView.person.formalName }}</div>'
        )
    })
});
```

However, when I run the script, "App.View.PersonProfile.Name" apparently cannot be found. Is this expected behaviour? And if so, what is the solution? Is it better to `extend` the `PersonProfile` abstract?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this not working is likely that the property "App.View.PersonProfile.Name" is not present in your app. Your code defines a property with lowercase n for name, that will exist on *instances* of the PersonView. So, there are multiple layers of issues here.

A better way to approach this would be to have a PersonView extending from Ember.View with a template. If you need subviews (it doesn't look like you would from your example, but maybe you have other needs), you would reference them from the template associated with PersonView.

If you try this approach and have a problem, please post a JS Fiddle that illustrates the problem in executable code. You can start from the one on emberjs.com/community.